# How to retrieve starting address of a thread in windows?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi

I'm working on a mini windows process explorer in C, I have a handle to a thread.
How can I retrieve starting address of that thread? Something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such question was already asked a few days ago. Here is a sample solution:

```
DWORD WINAPI GetThreadStartAddress(HANDLE hThread)
{
    NTSTATUS ntStatus;
    HANDLE hDupHandle;
    DWORD dwStartAddress;

    pNtQIT NtQueryInformationThread = (pNtQIT)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryInformationThread");

    if(NtQueryInformationThread == NULL) 
        return 0;

    HANDLE hCurrentProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    if(!DuplicateHandle(hCurrentProcess, hThread, hCurrentProcess, &hDupHandle, THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, 0)){
        SetLastError(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED);

        return 0;
    }

    ntStatus = NtQueryInformationThread(hDupHandle, ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, &dwStartAddress, sizeof(DWORD), NULL);
    CloseHandle(hDupHandle);
    if(ntStatus != STATUS_SUCCESS) 
       return 0;

    return dwStartAddress;

}
```

Source: http://forum.sysinternals.com/how-to-get-the-start-address-and-modu_topic5127_post18072.html#18072

You might have to include this file: http://pastebin.com/ieEqR0eL

Related question: [How to add ntdll.dll to project libraries with LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120710/how-to-add-ntdll-dll-to-project-libraries-with-loadlibrary-and-getprocaddress/11121140#11121140)

Comment: Thanks, but this function will return a number.
How can I use it as start address?

Comment: This function returns the start address of a thread in target process' address space. You use it in any way you only want (e.g. if you know the function definition you can cast it and call using `CreateRemoteThread` function).

Comment: Can I retrieve something like this: chrome.dll!chromeMain+0x11ded
using that number?

Comment: I think that you have to check in which module your start address is located (it doesn't have to be in .text segment of exe file but in e.g. `ntdll.dll` or `chrome.dll`), get the `ImageBaseAddress` of code in it and then calculate the offset (+0x11ded part). Function names can be retrieved by analyzing the DLL files directly (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx see PE File Exports section). Happy hacking!

Comment: It's the address of function's first byte in target process. You have to remember that it can be cast to a function pointer but the code is located in target process' address space.

Comment: Does this word for x86 and x64?

Answer (score 4):

[`NtQueryInformationThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283.aspx) with `ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress`. Another possibility is to walk the thread's stack with [`StackWalk64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650.aspx).

If you only need the start address, `NtQueryInformationProcess` is a *lot* simpler. Even with fairly terse coding, walking the stack takes a couple hundred [lines of code](http://ideone.com/KiB9r) or so.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a stack trace with [StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or a related function, and then parse it with the dbghelp.dll .

This CodeProject article explains it all in detail:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx