# ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY reading value from memory pointer in JNA

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I'm trying to read a (float) value from a pointer within a process which window is called `Age of Empires II: Definitive Edition`.

This is my code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class Main {

    final static long baseAddress = 0x02BC6620L;
    final static Pointer baseAddressPointer = new Pointer(baseAddress);
    final static int[] offsets = new int[]{0x00, 0x1A8, 0x00, 0x158, 0x28, 0x270};

    static Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32",Kernel32.class);
    static User32 user32 = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

    public static int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;
    public static int PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020;
    public static int PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008;

    public static interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary
    {
        final User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary ("user32", User32.class);
        WinDef.HWND FindWindowExA(WinDef.HWND hwndParent, WinDef.HWND childAfter, String className, String windowName);
        WinDef.HWND FindWindowA(String className, String windowName);
        void GetWindowThreadProcessId(WinDef.HWND hwnd, IntByReference intByReference);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("System.getProperty(\"sun.arch.data.model\") = " + System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
        int pid = getProcessId("Age of Empires II: Definitive Edition");
        System.out.println("pid = " + pid);
        com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE process = openProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, pid);

        long theDynAddress = findDynAddress(process, offsets);
        System.out.println("theDynAddress = " + theDynAddress);
        Pointer dynAddress = new Pointer(theDynAddress);

        Memory scoreMem = readMemory(process, dynAddress, 4);
        float score = scoreMem.getFloat(0);
        System.out.println(score);
    }

    public static Memory readMemory(com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE process, Pointer address, int bytesToRead) {
        IntByReference read = new IntByReference(0);
        Memory output = new Memory(bytesToRead);

        boolean readProcessMemorySucceeded = kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(process, address, output, bytesToRead, read);
        System.out.println("readProcessMemorySucceeded = " + readProcessMemorySucceeded);
        if (!readProcessMemorySucceeded) {
            int lasterrorReadMemory = kernel32.GetLastError();
            System.out.println("lasterror = " + lasterrorReadMemory);
        }

        return output;
    }

    public static int getProcessId(String window) {
        IntByReference pid = new IntByReference(0);
        user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(user32.FindWindowA(null, window), pid);

        return pid.getValue();
    }

    public static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE openProcess(int permissions, int pid) {
        return kernel32.OpenProcess(permissions, true, pid);
    }

    public static long findDynAddress(com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE process, int[] offsets)
    {

        int size = 4;
        Memory pTemp = new Memory(size);
        long pointerAddress = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < offsets.length; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                boolean test = kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(process, baseAddressPointer, pTemp, size, null);
                int lasterror = kernel32.GetLastError();
                System.out.println("test = " + test + ", lasterror = " + lasterror);
            }

            pointerAddress = ((pTemp.getInt(0)+offsets[i]));

            if(i != offsets.length-1)
                kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(process, new Pointer(pointerAddress), pTemp, size, null);


        }

        return pointerAddress;
    }

}
```

This is the terminal output after running the jar:

```
System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model") = 64
pid = 2192
test = false, lasterror = 299
theDynAddress = 1177510878
readProcessMemorySucceeded = false
lasterror = 299
1.64011448E10
```

Please note:

- As you can see, the jar is compiled for 64-bit.
- I run the jar with administrative privileges.
- The process I'm trying to get access to is also 64-bit.

I'm getting error 299 which is labeled as `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`. The value I'm getting seems to be random. What can I do to prevent this?

I have no problem accessing the same value using Cheat Engine:

[image: Cheat Engine screenshot]

Comment: You say you're reading a `float` value, but you're calling `scoreMem.getInt(0);` rather than `getFloat()`.  Are you sure the `lasterror` is coming from that final call and not a previous call?

Comment: @DanielWiddis You're right! I changed it to `scoreMem.getFloat(0)` and updated the code. Regarding `lasterror`, however, it's executed before `scoreMem`'s `getInt(0)` / `getFloat(0)`, so no way the `lasterror` is regarding that, right? I also added printing value of `test` to be sure - as you can see the value of `test` is `false`, so `ReadProcessMemory(...)` is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than looking at the final incorrect value, your debugging should focus on the first case of the error.  In this case, you've shown it's the initial `ReadProcessMemory()` call inside your `findDynAddress()` method, which attempts to read from the `Pointer` variable `baseAddressPointer`.

In the initial version of your code, you defined:

```java
final static long baseAddress = 0x02B7C950L;
final static Pointer baseAddressPointer = new Memory(baseAddress);
```

You've defined a base address (which I assume you got from somewhere else, it's generally dangerous to hardcode this) and then you attempt to create a pointer with it, but use the `Memory` class, a subclass of `Pointer`.   The argument for the `Memory` constructor is a size, and the constructor allocates new memory at a new address, given the size of its argument, in this case `0x02B7C950` bytes of memory, about 45.6 megabytes!

While you've allocated that memory (and thus your later code doesn't fail to read, as it's reading memory you "own") it contains random data.

You probably meant to do:

```java
final static Pointer baseAddressPointer = new Pointer(baseAddress);
```

---

After editing your code, you still have an error. In this case, you may be reading a memory address from the native code, but you have only allocated 4 bytes in which to store it with this:

```java
int size = 4;
Memory pTemp = new Memory(size);
```

And you're fetching what is supposed to be a 64-bit Pointer with `getInt()`:

```java
pointerAddress = ((pTemp.getInt(0)+offsets[i]));
```

You should be using 8 bytes to store the address, and use `getLong()` to fetch it after the call.  The prologue to the answer in the post you are referencing does mention you need to be careful about pointer sizes when using this approach.

---

One key thing is to understand symbols that CheatEngine uses.

Regarding the screenshot:

- `"AoE2DE_s.exe"` is the load address of the module with the same name. `lpmodinfo.lpBaseOfDll` is where it's retrieved in the code. This address can be seen in CheatEngine under Memory View -> View -> Enumerate DLL's and Symbols.
- `+02BC6620` part is simple arithmetic operation. The `02BC6620` is stored in the code as `baseAddress`.
- `->` means that the address on the left hand was accessed and under that address is stored another address which is on the right hand.

Finally, the code should look like this:

```
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Psapi;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    final static long baseAddress = 0x02BC6620L;
    private static final String MODULE_FILENAME = "AoE2DE_s.exe";
    private static final int SIZE_OF_LONG = 8;
    private static final String WINDOW_NAME = "Age of Empires II: Definitive Edition";
    final static int[] offsets = new int[]{0x00, 0x1A8, 0x00, 0x158, 0x28, 0x270};

    static Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32",Kernel32.class);
    static User32 user32 = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

    public static int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;
    public static int PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020;
    public static int PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008;

    public static interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary
    {
        final User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary ("user32", User32.class);
        WinDef.HWND FindWindowExA(WinDef.HWND hwndParent, WinDef.HWND childAfter, String className, String windowName);
        WinDef.HWND FindWindowA(String className, String windowName);
        void GetWindowThreadProcessId(WinDef.HWND hwnd, IntByReference intByReference);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("System.getProperty(\"sun.arch.data.model\") = " + System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
        int pid = getProcessId(WINDOW_NAME);
        System.out.println("pid = " + pid);

        com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE process = openProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, pid);;

        long theDynAddress = findDynAddress(process, offsets);
        System.out.printf("theDynAddress = %x\n", theDynAddress);
        Pointer dynAddress = new Pointer(theDynAddress);

        Memory scoreMem = readMemory(process, dynAddress, 8);
        float score = scoreMem.getFloat(0);
        System.out.println(score);
    }

    public static long getBaseAddress(String windowName, String moduleFilename) {
        int pid = getProcessId(windowName);

        com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE process = openProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, pid);
        WinDef.HMODULE[] hModules = new WinDef.HMODULE[100 * 4]; //I'm not sure how big the array should be, this is some big random number
        IntByReference lpcbNeeded = new IntByReference();
        Psapi.INSTANCE.EnumProcessModules(process, hModules, hModules.length, lpcbNeeded);

        hModules = Arrays.copyOf(hModules, lpcbNeeded.getValue() / SIZE_OF_LONG);

        for(WinDef.HMODULE m: hModules){
            Psapi.MODULEINFO lpmodinfo = new Psapi.MODULEINFO();

            if (!Psapi.INSTANCE.GetModuleInformation(process, m, lpmodinfo, lpmodinfo.size())) {
                //TODO: Error handling
            }
            char[] filename = new char[100 * 4];
            int filenameLength = Psapi.INSTANCE.GetModuleFileNameExW(process, m, filename, 100 * 4);
            String filenameString = new String(filename);
            if (filenameString.contains(moduleFilename)) {
                return readMemory(process, new Pointer((Pointer.nativeValue(lpmodinfo.lpBaseOfDll) + baseAddress)), SIZE_OF_LONG).getLong(0);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static Memory readMemory(com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE process, Pointer address, int bytesToRead) {
        IntByReference read = new IntByReference(0);
        Memory output = new Memory(bytesToRead);
        boolean readProcessMemorySucceeded = kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(process, address, output, bytesToRead, read);
        if (!readProcessMemorySucceeded) {
            int lasterrorReadMemory = kernel32.GetLastError();
            System.out.println("lasterror = " + lasterrorReadMemory);
        }

        return output;
    }

    public static int getProcessId(String window) {
        IntByReference pid = new IntByReference(0);
        user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(user32.FindWindowA(null, window), pid);

        return pid.getValue();
    }

    public static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE openProcess(int permissions, int pid) {
        return kernel32.OpenProcess(permissions, true, pid);
    }

    public static long findDynAddress(com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE process, int[] offsets)
    {
        long pointerAddress = getBaseAddress(WINDOW_NAME, MODULE_FILENAME);
        for(int i = 0; i < offsets.length; i++)
        {
            if (i != offsets.length-1) {
                pointerAddress = readMemory(process, new Pointer(pointerAddress + offsets[i]), SIZE_OF_LONG).getLong(0);
            } else {
                pointerAddress = pointerAddress + offsets[i];
            }
        }
        return pointerAddress;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Unfortunately, something still isn't right. I added printing out the result of the `findDynAddress` method to debug further. The concurrent results are not the same which makes me think the problem lies in this method. That code is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18849610/1252334. I don't quite understand, why there is `pointerAddress = ((pTemp.getInt(0)+offsets[i]));`. Why there's `getInt(0)` method on pTemp? As I understand it, it returns the value from the previously specified address. Why the value is needed? Shouldn't we just calculate the address?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the changes you've made in your code.  I believe you are fetching a memory address from that location and following each new memory address to find another one until you get to the score. Not unlike nested classes with fields in Java, except the internals are hidden from you. You're going to the nth field of an internally stored structure which points to another structure that you need the mth field of, which points to the pth field, etc.

Comment: Thank you. However, after changing `size` to `8` and `getInt` to `getLong` I still have the same error. I should also change `readMemory(...)`'s last param to `8`, I believe?

Comment: Yes, `bytesToRead` should be 8 there.  If you add some debug statements to print all the intermediate addresses (use `%x` format) you can see where it gets off track.

Comment: I managed to read the value! First, I substituted `final static long baseAddress = 0x02BC6620L;` with `14B5376F960L`. This is a calculated address from CheatEngine. Result of `"AoE2DE_s.exe"+02BC6620`. Second, I added dummy `0x00` as first element to `offsets` array. Although I was able to correctly get the value I wanted, I still need to calculate somehow `"AoE2DE_s.exe"+02BC6620` as it changes when the process is restarted. I don't understand how this works. Regarding another scan, according to CheatEngine `"AoE2DE_s.exe"` = `300905A4D`. How come `300905A4D + 02BC6620 = 264231CD4D0`?

Comment: I did mention hardcoding a pointer value was a bad idea. :)  When you run a program in Windows it stores the code at a particular "base address" and I presume that's what CheatEngine is looking for. In Java you can't add a number to a string.  I would guess you want to get the Thread starting address for the main program thread.  The [general code to do that is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147846/how-to-retrieve-starting-address-of-a-thread-in-windows).  You can probably parse a command line `wmic` query to get it from `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Thread`.

Comment: Althernately [here's the `C++` code to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564148/how-to-get-the-starting-base-address-of-a-process-in-c), which you could port to Java/JNA pretty easily.